# Need hint for $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(x+1)^\frac{1}{x}-e}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Please give me some hints or solution for this limit. I had it on my exam and I'm curious how to solve it.
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(x+1)^\frac{1}{x}-e}{x}
$$

Comment: See also: [How to solve this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/447429)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use l'Hospital, since $\;(x+1)^{1/x}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}e\;$ , writing

$$(x+1)^{1/x}=e^{\frac1x\log(x+1)}\implies\;\text{the limit thus is} \;\;\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\frac1x\log(x+1)}-e}x\;:$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\frac{\log(x+1)}x}-e}x\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-(x+1)\log(x+1)}{x^2(x+1)}e^{\frac{\log(x+1)}x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=-\frac e2$$

Comment: Thanks. At my exam I managed to get to the last equation before the result, but I have no idea how you get $-\frac{e}{2}$.

Comment: @EricTroy $$e^{\frac{\log(x+1)}x}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}e$$and $$\frac{x-(x+1)\log(x+1)}{x^2(x+1)}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}-\frac12$$ both by l'Hospital and continuity of the exponential function

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is by series expansion:
$$\frac{1}{x}\log(1+x) = \frac{1}{x} \left( x - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3) \right) = 
\left( 1 - \frac{x}{2} + O(x^2) \right)
$$
$$
(x+1)^{1/x} = e^{\frac{1}{x}\log(1+x) } = e^{\left( 1 - \frac{x}{2} + O(x^2) \right)}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left( 1 - \frac{x}{2} + O(x^2) \right)^n}{n!}  
$$
$$
(x+1)^{1/x}-e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left( 1 - \frac{x}{2} + O(x^2) \right)^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\left( 1 - \frac{x}{2} + O(x^2) \right)^n-1}{n!}
$$
$$
\frac{(x+1)^{1/x}-e}{x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\left( 1 - n\frac{x}{2} + O(x^2) \right)-1}{xn!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{ - n\frac{x}{2} + O(x^2) }{xn!} 
$$
$$
\frac{(x+1)^{1/x}-e}{x} = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n + O(x)}{n!} = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n }{n!} +O(x)  
$$
$$
\frac{(x+1)^{1/x}-e}{x} = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{n}{n!} +O(x) =
-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{m=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{(m+1)!} +O(x) = -\frac{e}{2} + O(x)
$$
from which it follows that 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(x+1)^{1/x}-e}{x} = -\frac{e}{2} $$

Comment: Could you please describe how you get from $\left( 1-\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)\right)^n$ to $1-n\frac{x}{2} + O(x^2)$?

Comment: Do you really think this is "the easiest way"? Easier than, say l'Hospital? It is a nice way, though...but easiest?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Consider the function $f(x) = (x + 1)^{1/x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = e$. Then $f$ is right-continuous at everywhere and the limit you are asked to find is the right-derivative of $f$ at $x = 0$, if it exists. So find $f'$ and evaluate it at $x = 0$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281%2Bx%29^%281%2Fx%29%29%27

It can't be evaluated at 0, or am I wrong?

Comment: He explicitly defined the function such
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} (x+1)^{1/x}&\text{ if }x\neq 0\\ e&\text{ if } x=0 \end{cases} $$

Comment: Oops, sorry. I didn't notice.

Comment: However it turns out the form of the derivative is ugly and requires repeated applications of l'Hopital. Probably better to do what Timbuc has done instead and use l'Hopital on the original expression.