# Find $A=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x} - e + \frac{ex}{2}}{x^2})$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:**
>
> Find  the value $$A=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x} - e  + \frac{ex}{2}}{x^2})$$

I found the value $$A=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }(\frac{(1+x)^{1/x} - e  + \frac{ex}{2}}{x^2})=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }( \frac{e- e + ex/2}{x^2}) =0  $$

Is this correct ?

Comment: No. That first step is not right but even if it was, how would that last limit be $0$...?

Comment: @StackTD by using L hospital rule

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447429/how-to-solve-this-limit-lim-limits-x-to0-frac1x1-x-ex

Comment: You mean the last step? After applying it once, the numerator becomes a constant but the denominator is still $2x$...

Comment: I assume OP mistook the limit as being to infinity rather than 0

Comment: The searched limit is given by $$\frac{11}{24}e$$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you know Taylor series
$$a=(1+x)^{\frac 1x}\implies \log(a)={\frac 1x}\log(1+x)={\frac 1x}\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right) \right)$$ that is to say 
$$\log(a)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Continue with Taylor using
$$a=e^{\log(a)}=e-\frac{e }{2}x+\frac{11 e }{24}x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Comment: @ ..@.claude  im not getting ur last sentence  $a = e^{loga}$    can u elaboarte that  how   e  - e/2x +......my question is that how  $e$  come  ?